# Snowflake Copy Into / List - Inconsistent behavior of Pattern?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 stages defined as follows:

- stage 1:

  - name = `prefect.project_name.project_name`
  - url = `s3://mycompany-data-prod-secret-stuff/`
- stage 2:

  - name = `prefect.prod_customername.prefect_flows_snowflake_load_customername`
  - url = `s3://mycompany-data-prod-prefect/flows/snowflake_load_customername/`

Ultimately I want to `copy into` from all csv files starting with certain words in both buckets. I'm using `list` queries here to test the pattern. The behavior of pattern seems to be the same between `copy into` and `list`

When I run the following query (query1), it correctly matches files for stage 1:

```
list @prefect.project_name.project_name/customername/20230915/cleaned/
pattern = 'TLA_Secret_List.*\.csv'
;
```

When I run this query2 on stage 2, it does not match any files:

```
list @prefect.prod_customername.prefect_flows_snowflake_load_customername/output
pattern = 'Mycompany.*\.csv'
;
```

When I run this query3 on stage 2, it does match files correctly:

```
list @prefect.prod_customername.prefect_flows_snowflake_load_customername/
pattern = 'flows/snowflake_load_customername/output/Mycompany.*\.csv'
;
```

It looks like the queries on stage 1 work fine if I put the filename in the pattern, whereas for stage 2 I need to include the prefixes in the pattern.

My question is: Why do query1 and query3 give me the files I want, while query2 does not?

My only theory is that because I included a path in the url for stage2 the behavior of `pattern` is altered. However I didn't find anything in the docs about this.

Edit:

`list` always returns the "full name" of the s3 object for all 3 example queries given above:

- query1: `s3://mycompany-data-prod-secret-stuff/customername/20230915/cleaned/TLA_Secret_List_-_12SEP2023.csv`
- query2: No Results
- query3: `s3://mycompany-data-prod-prefect/flows/snowflake_load_customername/output/Mycompany_SecretThing_202305.csv`

Comment: Hi - can you update your question with the output of query 3 (specifically the name column) so we can see what the files and paths are within stage2?

Comment: @NickW: question updated

Comment: I assume the list commands you original gave in your question are generic and not the actual commands (as they don't align with what you've not shown as the output of the list commands). Please can you update your question so that the list commands are the actual ones you are running and all the information in your question is consistent? I'm guessing your issue is related to the regex using the pattern parameter but without having the actual commands you are using (and the actual file names you're running against) it's difficult to be sure

Comment: @NickW well, the names used in them were generic to make the question more readable. I've edited the question and made the names less generic, only replacing words were necessary, keeping all special characters, and keeping capitalization.

E.g. `s3://google-data-prod-alien-research/nestle/20230915/cleaned/UFO_Sightings_List_-_12SEP2023.csv`

turned into

`s3://mycompany-data-prod-secret-stuff/customername/20230915/cleaned/TLA_Secret_List_-_12SEP2023.csv`

Comment: Also edited the Edit to align with the queries instead of the stages.